# Dynamic field validation (Livewire) - works but cannot reference error bucket

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to validate dynamically added fields.

I can use this for my rules:

```
'pageElements.*.value' => 'required',
```

…and I get this in my error bucket:

```
{"pageElements.0.value":["The pageElements.0.value field is required."]}
```

However when I try and output this to the user, using the below, nothing is shown:

```
@error('pageElements.{{ $key }}.value') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
```

…but does if I reference the KEY specifically like:

```
@error('pageElements.0.value') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
```

Of course, I need to reference each field with the $key value. But it looks like I cannot reference the error bucket with {{.$key }}.

Any ideas to get around this please?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the correct way

```
@error('pageElements.'.$key.'.value') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
```

...just needed to use PHP syntax instead of JS

```
pageElements.'.$key.'.value'
```